# Are such usages acceptable with native speakers as'Our Bombay city or Punjab National Bank?

Tags: word-usage

My question is about the usage of pronoun before the names of cities, institutions, banks etc. as , "our Bombay", "your Bangalore", "our Canara Bank". Is the usage of pronouns before such names appropriate?

I find Indians often using pronouns before proper nouns..as 'Our Bombay city'..or 'our Punjab National Bank'. How far are such usages acceptable?

Comment: What do you mean "how far"? What makes you ask? What's the context? Please flesh out your question to make it easier for us to answer :)

Comment: Natives of where? The usage you describe is presumably acceptable to native speakers of Indian English. Natives of Britain would probably say "Our city of XXX".

Answer (score 2):

It's acceptable, though rather odd, and probably an Indian dialect use.

The "pronouns" like "our" or "your" function as determiners, to determine the particular item.  You can say "our city" to distinguish it from other cities.

But "Our Bombay" doesn't identify the city, since there is only one (famous) city called Bombay.  It can be used rhetorically to cause the hearer to identify more with the speaker. It can be used to write persuasively.

> Our Bombay is no longer a tidy city. We must clean our Bombay!

> As Punjabis we should support our institutions.  We should use our Punjab National Bank, and not foreign banks!

But generally the pronoun is not needed, so leave it out.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is a regional idiom of Indian / South Asian English, in which case I would say it is completely 'acceptable' to use in that context.

From your question, I get the impression the pronouns are used when someone wants to express a sense of collective ownership in some way. In that regard I would say it is unusual but not unknown elsewhere in the world.

One example that's common in North America is to say 'our nation's capital' to refer to Ottawa, and (I believe) Washington DC. By contrast, anybody calling London (UK) 'our nation's capital' would get a very peculiar look from the locals.

Moreover, it wouldn't be out of line to say something like "your Toronto has really improved since the last time I visited", but it would be unusual. However, it's also something that in a context like politics or marketing is much more likely to be chosen for the previously-mentioned reasons of expressing a sense of collective unity and ownership.